# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x^{n}-x)}\, \mathrm{d}x,\quad n>0$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, complex-integration

I know from [Discussing the Integral of $\exp(-x^n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875224/discussing-the-integral-of-exp-xn) that 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{n}}\mathrm{d}x=\Gamma(1+1/n),\quad n>0.$$

But how to evaluate 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(x^{n}-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x,\quad n>0?$$

The only substitution i found is
$$\text{Let}\quad x=\ln u, \quad \text{then}\quad e^{x}=u, \quad \text{and} \quad \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{u}\mathrm{d}u.$$
Then
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(x^{n}-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-(\ln u)^{n}}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
But after this, I am stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: Your title is probably wrong. You seem to mean $\exp(-x^n + x)$, not $\exp(x^n+x)$.

Comment: Which is the integral? The one in the title which surely diverges if $n>1$ or the one in the question?

Comment: This integral is going to be a special function which means that there's no really nice way to represent it, and depending on your outlook, the special function representation might be just a different way to write the integral (i.e. it's different notation for the same thing).

Comment: Sorry, @Cameron Williams. It was a typo. I have corrected it now,

Comment: The title and the body still don't match though.

Answer (score 2):

*Just to add one more nightmare to marty cohen's list*.

For $n=6$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{12}  \,
   _0F_4\left(;\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{6},\frac{4}{3};\frac{1}{46656}\right)+\Gamma \left(\frac{7}{6}\right) \,
   _0F_4\left(;\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{6};\frac{1}{46656}\right)-$$ $$\frac{1}{9} \Gamma \left(-\frac{2}{3}\right) \,
   _0F_4\left(;\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{6};\frac{1}{46656}\right)-\frac{1}{108} \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right) \,
   _0F_4\left(;\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{6},\frac{4}{3},\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{46656}\right)-$$ $$\frac{1}{864} \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{6}\right) \,
   _0F_4\left(;\frac{7}{6},\frac{4}{3},\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{3};\frac{1}{46656}\right)+\frac{1}{720} \,
   _1F_5\left(1;\frac{7}{6},\frac{4}{3},\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{3},\frac{11}{6};\frac{
   1}{46656}\right)$$ which is $\approx 1.56900$

I may have a mistake somewhere since the values I obtained are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(x^{n}-x)}\,dx \\
 2 & 1.73023 \\
 3 & 1.57661 \\
 4 & 1.55602 \\
 5 & 1.55968 \\
 6 & 1.56900 \\
 7 & 1.57924 \\
 8 & 1.58899 \\
 9 & 1.59786 \\
 10 & 1.60582 \\
 11 & 1.61291 \\
 12 & 1.61924
\end{array}
\right)$$ showing a minimum

Comment: For sure, this is given by a CAS !

Comment: When $n\to \infty$ define integral is : $e-1$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk. This is fine ! SInce we know the value for $n=3$, there is a minimum somewhere ! I just feel stupid (once more). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfy gives increasingly complicated expressions
for increasing values of $n$.
The complexity is the same
whether the exponent has
$x$ or $-x$.

For $n=2$:

$\int_0^∞ e^{-(x^2 - x)} dx = (1/2) e^{1/4} \sqrt{π} (erf(1/2) + 1)≈1.73023
$

For $n=3$:

$\int_0^∞ e^{-(x^3 - x)} dx 
= (1/18) (3 _1 F_2(1;4/3, 5/3;1/27) + 4 3^{2/3} π Bi(1/3^{1/3}))≈1.57661
$

($Bi$ is the Airy $Bi$ function)

For $n=5$:

$\int_0^∞ e^{-(x^5 - x)} dx 
= (1/120) (_1 F_4(1;6/5, 7/5, 8/5, 9/5;1/3125) + 4 (30 Γ(6/5) _0 F_3(;2/5, 3/5, 4/5;1/3125) + 6 Γ(2/5) _0 F_3(;3/5, 4/5, 6/5;1/3125) + 5 Γ(8/5) _0 F_3(;4/5, 6/5, 7/5;1/3125) + Γ(4/5) _0 F_3(;6/5, 7/5, 8/5;1/3125)))≈1.55968
$

Comment: Would you mind checking the numerical value for $n=6$ I gave in my so-called answer ? It looks that there will be aminimum ! I have probably an error somewhere. Thanks.