# Turn $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^4}dx$ into a proper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, substitution

I'm asked to transform the improper integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^4}dx$$ into a proper integral.

---

What I tried:

Substituting $x = \tan(x)$ and $\frac{dx}{ds} = \sec^2(s)$

The integral becomes $$\int_{0}^{+ \frac{\pi}{2}} e^{- \tan^4(s)} \sec^2{(s)} ds$$

Is that correct ? Is there a way to go further ?

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875224/discussing-the-integral-of-exp-xn

Comment: @user159888 Uh sorry, didn't see that.  Will my question get closed as duplicate ? Is there anything I can do aside of deleting the question ? I still hope it could add value to the site.