# Upper bound for integration of exponential function

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I am working on finding an upper bound of the function:

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp{\left[-(x + \frac{b x^a}{t})\right]} \, dx.
> $$
> where $a, b > 0$ and $1> t > 0$.

I am attempting to show whether this can be upper bounded by a linear function of $t$, such as $\beta \cdot t$. My numerical experiments suggest that this function is increasing in $t$, converging to 1. As $t \rightarrow 0$, the value converges to $0$.

Is there a known solution to this integral, or could this be approximated in a simple expression? Can $\beta$ be expressed as a function of $a$ and $b$? Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax%C3%A9n_integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest an upper bound by using the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality) and this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1875236/195378):

$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\left(x + \frac{bx^a}{t}  \right)  \right)dx } &\le \int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-   2\sqrt{x \cdot \frac{bx^a}{t} }  \right)dx\\&=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-   2\sqrt{ \frac{b}{t} } \cdot x^{\frac{a+1}{2}} \right)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \left(2\sqrt{ \frac{b}{t}}\right)^{-\frac{2}{a+1}}\cdot\exp\left(-    x^{\frac{a+1}{2}} \right)dx\\
&=\color{red}{\underbrace{\left(2\sqrt{b}\right)^{-\frac{2}{a+1}}\cdot \Gamma\left(1+ \frac{2}{a+1}  \right)}_{=: \beta} \cdot t^{\frac{1}{a+1}}}
\end{align}$$

And if you want a bound that is a linear function of $t$, it suffices to remind that  $ t^{\frac{1}{a+1}}<t$ for $a>0$.